# how to add additional select columns in symfony 1.0

Tags: php, symfony1

How can I add an additional column to my select query so when I execute TableA::doSelect($c) I could also get some columns of TableB? It does not seem that addSelectColumn is available in symfony 1.0, unless I'm missing something.

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->setDistinct();
// need to add TableB::START_DATE to select
$c->addJoin(TableA::ID, TableB::ID);
...
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn ( TableB::START_DATE );
$result = TableA::doSelect($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **addSelectColumn()** with Symfony 1.0 but should avoid adding **doSelect()** in such cases.

This method is executing an object and expects to get all its fields in the same order they are described in the schema file. Trying to skip a field or add one from another table will be ignored in the result set.

Depending on your Propel version you could try and use the *doSelectStmt(), doSelectRS()* or *doSelectJoin()* methods instead.

Or go with the easiest way and just use a **prepareStatement()**:

```
$con = Propel::getConnection();
$sql = "SELECT `table1`.field1, `table2`.field2 FROM `table1` JOIN `table2`. ON ..."

$st = $con->prepareStatement($sql);
$rs = $st->executeQuery();

while ($rs->next())
{
...
}
```

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/cookbook/1_0/en/behaviors